# Mapping many-to-one relations in .Net core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using .Net Core EF how do I map a many-to-one relation?

I am trying to map a many-to-one relation. All of the samples I see assume that you map a one-to-one relation (ie Attendee has the FK of the ticket and the ticket has the FK of the Attendee) or they assume that the subordinate object will hold a collection of the main object. The example I saw was an `Order` and an `OrderStatus`.

The `Order` has a FK of the `OrderStatus`.  But to map the relation in .Net they had the `OrderStatus` with a `List<Order>` and a [ForeignKey] annotation pointing to the Order.

This seems silly.  What would I want an `OrderStatus` to know about ALL of the `Orders` that have that status???

Example:

```
class Order {
    long orderId;
    OrderStatus status;
    ...
}

class OrderStatus {
   long orderStatusId;
   String code;
   String description;
   int severityLevel;
   ...
}
```

In the Database the Order table would have a FK column holding the orderStatusId.

How does one do a simple many-to-one mapping for this?

Comment: You've got it the wrong way around, can you create a new project and dB and do it with DB-first approach to see what code-first is generated?

Comment: Have you tried to use the code you posted? If you use correct properties (i.e `public long OrderId { get; set; }`, this should work just fine

Comment: I have a DB but how do I generate the code from that?  All I have seen is fluent builders and annotations.

Comment: @CoryWandling Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db) you are looking for the scaffolding command

Answer (score 1):

> What would I want an OrderStatus to know about ALL of the Orders that have that status???

Yes! possible!. write your model classes as follows:

```
public class OrderStatus 
{
   [Key]
   public long orderStatusId { get; set; }
   public string string code { get; set; }
   public string description { get; set; }
   public int severityLevel { get; set; }
   ...........

}

public class Order 
{
    [Key]
    public long orderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderStatus")]
    public long orderStatusId { get; set; }
    ..........

    public OrderStatus OrderStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the query:

```
var orders =  _dbContext.Orders.Where(o => o.orderStatusId == 1).ToList(); // <-- Here is all the Orders with statusId '1'
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Wow! Thank you so so much! I did not notice this fatal mistake :)

Comment: But that's my point.  Your OrderStatus has a ```public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }```.  I should not have to do that.

Comment: @CoryWandling You don't have to, that's why it was taken out

Comment: Ok. I see.  Thank you.

Comment: @CoryWandling If it works for then please click on the check sign left to the answer. I have said so as you are new to the stack overflow. Thank you. Happy Coding!